# Error Loading WSDL in SOAP UI for SpringBoot Project

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, xsd, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to test the wsdl link in SOAP UI but getting below error while loading the wsdl in SOAP UI

```
Error loading [http://localhost:8080/service/Mi.xsd]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null
```

Plese find the xsd below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://exe/Services" 
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://exe/Services" xmlns:s2="COM.Services" 
xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<s:import namespace="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" schemaLocation="Mi.xsd" /> 

    -----
    -----
</s:schema>
```

wsdl also opening in browser without any issues.

and also tried by specifying the MI xsd in soap ui directory even facing the same issue.

Please suggest on this.

Comment: If are you able to see it opening in browser, then try to save it from browser and use that wsdl in soapui and see if that helps.

Comment: @Rao, Yes working but not coming all the services which has in XSD. Missing services which are imported from other xsd. Please suggest on this.

Comment: It could be that inline xsd are not available locally or not being downloaded when you use the location of xsd referred in wsdl.

Comment: @Rao, I have provided the xsd's in same path but it is taking the path "http://localhost:8080/service/Mi.xsd" like this. Due to this getting error.Thanks.